# NoMethodError with renamed nested resources (false route using link_to)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nested-routes

I've ran into a problem which causes `link_to @resource` to fail.

My view:

```
<% @test_thing = Bar.first #This one belongs to Foo.first %>
<%= link_to "test link", @test_thing %>
```

produces this error:

```
NoMethodError
undefined method `bar_path' for #<#<Class:0x007fd799bc1088>:0x007fd799bc8400>
```

**Why does rails not produce the correct route using `thing1_thing2_path`?**

routes.rb:

```
resources :foo, as: "thing1", path: "thing2" do
  resources :bar, as: "thing2", path: "thing2"
end
```

In my models, "Foo" `has_many :bars` and "Bar" `belongs_to :foo`

rake routes:

```
thing1_thing2_index GET    /thing2/:thing1_id/thing2(.:format)          bar#index
                    POST   /thing2/:thing1_id/thing2(.:format)          bar#create
  new_thing1_thing2 GET    /thing2/:thing1_id/thing2/new(.:format)      bar#new
 edit_thing1_thing2 GET    /thing2/:thing1_id/thing2/:id/edit(.:format) bar#edit
      thing1_thing2 GET    /thing2/:thing1_id/thing2/:id(.:format)      bar#show
                    PATCH  /thing2/:thing1_id/thing2/:id(.:format)      bar#update
                    PUT    /thing2/:thing1_id/thing2/:id(.:format)      bar#update
                    DELETE /thing2/:thing1_id/thing2/:id(.:format)      bar#destroy
       thing1_index GET    /thing2(.:format)                            foo#index
                    POST   /thing2(.:format)                            foo#create
         new_thing1 GET    /thing2/new(.:format)                        foo#new
        edit_thing1 GET    /thing2/:id/edit(.:format)                   foo#edit
             thing1 GET    /thing2/:id(.:format)                        foo#show
                    PATCH  /thing2/:id(.:format)                        foo#update
                    PUT    /thing2/:id(.:format)                        foo#update
                    DELETE /thing2/:id(.:format)                        foo#destroy
               root GET    /                                            bar#index
```

I'm using rails 4, but I had the same problem with rails 3.
I fell like it's a bug in rails, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I think your way is `thing1_thing2_index_path`

Comment: no, because i'm linking to a single "Bar" and not all of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not rename your routes. Remove the `as:` argument:

```
resources :foo, path: "thing2" do
  resources :bar, path: "thing2"
end
```

Apart from that, you need to hand it both objects in order to produce the correct path:

```
<%= link_to "test link", [@test_thing.foo, @test_thing] %>
```

Comment: Same problem: undefined method `foo_bar_path' for #<#<Class:0x007f2e28802958>:0x007f2e3b6eabe8>

Comment: @HansWürstchen Ah, you're renaming the route with `:as`. Remove that from your routes and it'll work as expected.

Comment: well that's the whole problem. I do want the renamed routes.

Comment: @HansWürstchen what for? Maybe we can find another way to achieve that.

Comment: for example when you have `albums` and `album_images`, but also got `xyz_images` for other resources, you wouldn't like to have a path like `album/13/album_image/37` but rather `album/13/image/37`.

Comment: @HansWürstchen You are confusing `as:` and `path:` - they have different purposes. `as:` defines how the *route helper* is named (eg. `album_album_image_path`). `path:` defines how *the URL* looks (eg. `resources :album_images, path: 'images'` => `/album/13/images/37`).  So you can have custom URLs that still work automatically with link_to.

Comment: thanks! worked :)
but i'm still wondering why it can't handle `as:` - maybe a bug?

Comment: @HansWürstchen no, it works like it is supposed to - it renames the route helpers. Rails builds on conventions: hand `link_to` an object of class `AlbumImage`, and it looks for an `album_image_path`. 

If there isn't one, because you renamed `album_image_path` to `foo_path` by declaring `resources :album_image, as: :foo`, you will have to pass the link to `link_to` directly, because you broke Rails' convention.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried passing the link explicitly? Something like:

```
<%= link_to "test link", bar_path(@test_thing) %>
```

...or whatever the correct *_path(variable) you should be using?

(Sorry, the test, and bar, and thing1, thing2 things got really confusing over here :P)

Comment: yes, `thing1_thing2_path(@test_thing.foo, @test_thing)` is working fine.

Comment: This is not an answer.  It should have been a comment.

Comment: Yeah, but SO told me I couldn't add a comment with less than 50 reputation, so, sorry about that.